# Angular 1 - How to delay render until ng-repeat has completed?

Tags: angularjs

I have a container component that renders a bunch of children using `ng-repeat`.  Currently, they appear to render in one-by-one - however, with the way my app works I don't want to show any child until all are rendered.  Otherwise, there is a noticeable trickle as they render in that causes a "flicker" of sorts.  How can I do this?

**search-filter-container.js:**

```
myModule.directive('searchFilterContainer', ['COMPONENTS_PATH', '$timeout', function(COMPONENTS_PATH) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: COMPONENTS_PATH + '/proj/search/search-filter-container.html',
        controller: 'SearchFilterContainerCtrl',
        scope: {
            searchFilters: "<"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.init();
        }
    };
}]);

myModule.controller('SearchFilterContainerCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        // do stuff
    };
}]);
```

**search-filter-container.html:**

```
<span>
    <search-filter ng-repeat="filter in ::searchFilters" filter-info="::filter"></search-filter>
</span>
```

**search-filter.js:**

```
myModule.directive('searchFilter', ['COMPONENTS_PATH', '$timeout', function(COMPONENTS_PATH) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: COMPONENTS_PATH + '/proj/search/search-filter.html',
        controller: 'SearchFilterCtrl',
        scope: {
            filterInfo: '<'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.init();
        }
    };
}]);

myModule.controller('SearchFilterCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.filterText = '';

    /**
     * Initialize the search filter.
     */
    $scope.init = function() {
        //do stuff
    };
}]);
```

**search-filter.html:**

```
<div class="search-filter rectangular-pill">
    {{filterText}}
</div>
```

Comment: it depends on what is happening inside the `init` function of each child, but in general, `ng-repeat` isn't dependent on it's children.  It *sounds like* what is occurring is that the children are each doing their own data fetch from the server, and these fetches aren't dependent on each other either.

Comment: you *might* be able to have a `loaded` flag for all the children that you can pass out of the component, and use `ng-show` to only show the main `div` when all the children's `loaded` flag are set true.  (don't use `ng-if`, since that wouldn't even activate the components in the first place).

Comment: Isn't `ng-cloak` doing the job?